# Implement a RESTful Web service with jersey

Tags: rest, jersey

Hi folks i implemented a [tutorial](http://www.theserverside.com/tip/RESTful-Web-services-made-easy) for RESTful Web services with jersey.

My Project Setup is as follows:

Folder structure:

- restful

  - Web-INF

    - classes\com\mcnz\ws

      - HelloWorldResource.java
      - HelloWorldResource.class
    - lib

      - some libs (jersey 1.6 archive)
    - web.xml

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"> 
    <servlet>
       <servlet-name>RestfulContainer</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
           <param-value>com.mcnz.ws</param-value>
       </init-param>
           <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>RestfulContainer</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

HelloWorldResource.java

```
package com.mcnz.ws;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
@Path("helloworld")
public class HelloWorldResource {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Rest Never Sleeps";
    }
}
```

I builded the war and all seems to run but after deployment to a tomcat 7 the url

```
http://localhost:8080/restful/resources/helloworld
```

does not respond

here my 
[.war](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dwoo0s9hfbtp4vz/restful.war)

Answer (score 1):

I think that your project structure is a mess.Why are your REST resources in the `WEB-INF` folder? You should have placed them in `src/main/java`. I recommend following [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html) tutorial for your first REST project. Also looking again at your folder structure i would recommend using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) for dependency management.You can find some tutorials [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/maven-tutorials/).

Answer (score 0):

You have the path a the class level, try putting it at the method level (after the @GET statement)
You can also leave the first one and another one after the @GET for example

This is one sample of mine

```
@Path("/user/")
public class UserResource {

    // Method for Registering a User, receives and replies a JSON
    @POST
    @Path("/register")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public StatusResult register(UserRegistrationRequest urr) {
        //Calls the controller to register the producer, and returns result
        StatusResult result = UserController.register(urr);
        return result;
    }
```

You would call it like this localhost:8080/restful/resources/user/register in this case

Comment: The `PATH` is not the problem.You could do a quick try.His code is valid.You could only have `PATH` at class level and can use all the HTTP methods (ex: one GET method, on POST method...etc) with same parameters

Answer (score 0):

Recently I successfully implementing Jersey RESTful WEb service in Liferay..

You can find it...

[Jersey Implementation](http://www.liferay.com/web/pradip.bhatt/blog)